# Connection issues with Talend Open Studio for Big data and Couchbase Server

Tags: couchbase, talend

I want to move data from MySQL to Couchbase server using Talend. I have a new installation for Couchbase with the portal having the username Administrator and the password administrator. I also have Xampp installed with data in the data database.

Using Talend, I have setup the MySql connection, set up the credentials and schema and mapped the JSON. For couchbase, here is what I have setup

[image: couchb]

When I run this job however, I get this error:

```
WARN com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP:  Connection 
problems with URI http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools ...skipping
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP.readToString(ConfigurationProviderHTTP.java:344)
at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP.readPools(ConfigurationProviderHTTP.java:144)
at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.ConfigurationProviderHTTP.getBucketConfiguration(ConfigurationProviderHTTP.java:126)
at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnectionFactory.getVBucketConfig(CouchbaseConnectionFactory.java:233)
at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.<init>(CouchbaseClient.java:256)
at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.<init>(CouchbaseClient.java:222)
at local_project.couchbasedummy_0_1.couchbasedummy.tCouchbaseOutput_1_MidProcess(couchbasedummy.java:1420)
at local_project.couchbasedummy_0_1.couchbasedummy$1ThreadXMLField_tCouchbaseOutput_1_In.run(couchbasedummy.java:619)
Exception in component tCouchbaseOutput_1_Out (couchbasedummy)
java.lang.NullPointerException
.....
.....
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried connecting directly via command line to Couchbase?

Comment: No @tobi6 I have not. How do I do this?

Comment: Google to the rescue! https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/3.x/admin/CLI/cbcli-intro.html so I suppose first find the cli folder and then try to login with the parameters provided there.

Comment: Thanks...let me look at this

Comment: Did you have any luck with this and manage to resolve it?  I am hitting the same wall!

Comment: no @JHenzel I did not. I ended up writing some code to help me work on this